# $S_{10}$ has a subgroup of idex $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question**:(True/False) $S_{10}$ has a subgroup of idex $4$.

**Attempt** I tried to use Lagrange's theorem $|S_{10}|=[S_{10}:H]|H|\Rightarrow |H|=\dfrac{10!}{4}$ but can't continue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know what the normal subgroups of $S_{10}$ are?

Comment: I think that it is only $A_{10}$

Comment: Ok. Now consider the action of $S_{10}$ on the cosets of such a subgroup. This gives a homomorphism to $S_4$. What can you say about the kernel of this homomorphism?

Comment: I found that  $ker(\phi)=\{g\in S_{10}:gxH=xH  \forall x\in S_{10} \}$ but can't continue

Comment: Well, what could the size of that kernel be?

Comment: The fact that $A_{10}$ is the only nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $S_{10}$ is not completely elementary and uses the simplicity of $A_{n}$ for $n \ge 5$. I would expect anyone who understood the proof of that to find this question trivial.

Comment: @giannispapav Perhaps you could also use that $\;\ker\phi\;$ is the maximal normal subgroup of $\;S_{10}\;$ contained in $\;H\;$ ...and observe that Derek's comment would even be taken as a hint, too.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks!I will check the proof,I just started studying group theory and lack of the knowledge of such proofs

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $ker(\phi)\lhd S_{10}\Rightarrow |ker(\phi)|=\dfrac{10!}{2}$

Comment: @giannispapav You've just "started" to study group theory? Because this is relatively advanced stuff in basic group theory. I'd expect students would read this stuff at least in the middle of a one-semester course...

Comment: @ DonAntonio I started 2 weeks ago

Comment: @giannispapav But it can't be the size of $\;\ker\phi\;$ is $\;\frac{10!}2\;$ , right? Then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in details:

Following my comment and the other ones: Could it be $\;\ker\phi=A_{10}\;$ ? Observe that after answering this you obtain a straightforward contradiction by considering the size of $\;\ker\phi\;$ ...

Comment: Mmm I think I got it! We have a contradiction since $2\not= 4!$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you: the first part is that $\;10!/2 >10!/4!\;$ , but the actual contradiction, after the above , is to conclude that $\;\ker\phi=1\;$ and thus $\;S_{10}\;$ is embedded in $\;S_4\;$ ...!

Comment: Aa $ker(\phi)\not= A_{10}\Rightarrow ker(\phi)=1$ ok ok

Comment: @giannispapav Exactly, as there are no other normal subgroups in $\;S_{10]\;$ except  the group itself, which cannot be as the mentioned homomorphism is *not* trivial.

Answer (score 5):

Using the simplicity of $A_n$ for $n \ge 5$ to prove a result like this feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, so here is a moderately elementary argument.

If $|G:H| = 4$ with $G=S_{10}$, then the action on cosets gives a homomorphism $\tau: G \to S_4$. Since $5$ does not divide $|S_4|$, all $5$-cycles lie in $\ker \tau$ and hence in $H$.

In particular, $h_1=(1,2,4,5,6)\in H$ and $h_2=(1,3,4,5,6) \in H$, and $h_1h_2^{-1} = (1,2,3)$ (or $h_2^{-1}h_1$ depending on how you compose permutations).

So $H$ contains all $3$-cycles, which generate $A_{10}$, and hence $A_{10}\le H$, contradicting $|G:H|=4$.

Comment: Thank you very much!That really helped me!